# Are roads more slippery when it's raining?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

Are roads more slippery when wet? I would like to know if handling the car would be harder when the roads are wet from rain. [Wet roads from rain affect tire traction in the GTA games](http://gta.wikia.com/Weather) - I would like to know if SR3 has a similar game mechanic.

Side note: I'm using a vehicle physics mod that among other changes, makes vehicle tire traction lower, and a weather mod that makes it rain more often. Tire traction and rain are still part of the mechanics of the vanilla non-modded game, though.

[image: Slippery when wet?]

Comment: I've [searched](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=saints+row+%283+OR+third%29+road+slippery+%28rain+OR+wet%29) but can't seem to find anything about this for SR3.

Comment: Well, the fact that you're using a physics mod makes this hard to pinpoint. The effect of rain in the base game could be near-negligible - so we couldn't accurately measure it - but the mod may increase that effect by a significant amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot speak objectively, but from hundreds of hours of play-time (523 to be exact) (and favouritism of the SR3 driving mechanics), I opine that the roads are not more slippery when it's raining. Or if they are, it's negligible.

Comment: Is the game, Saints Row IV, really THAT much fun to spend 523 hours in it? Or are you talking about Saint's Row in general?

Comment: @VascovdEng He's talking about SR3. SR3 is way more fun and gets more replayability if you install mods. I'm not surprised with that playtime amount at all. SR4's cool too. Mods are not as polished as SR3's, though (as the game was just recently released).

Comment: I haven't played with any mods. I play(ed) on OnLive, where you can't install mods. And yes, SR:TT, not SRIV.